# static_assert failed "typex::value" failure while deserialising binary data using boost

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

The code below serialises and de serialises the class and structure's members.
The serialisation is working but i have encountered the below error while trying to deserialise it using `oarch >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(outObj);`

Is there any big miss in the code that i have not realiased and not implemented .

> In file included from main.cpp:1:
>   In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp:21:
>   In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/archive/binary_oarchive_impl.hpp:22:
>   In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/archive/basic_binary_oarchive.hpp:33:
>   In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/archive/detail/common_oarchive.hpp:22:
>   In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_oarchive.hpp:23:
>   In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/archive/detail/oserializer.hpp:68:
>   /usr/local/include/boost/archive/detail/check.hpp:162:5: error: static_assert failed "typex::value"
>       BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(typex::value);
>       ^                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   /usr/local/include/boost/static_assert.hpp:70:41: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT'

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/binary_object.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

#include <map>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/split_member.hpp>

struct values
{
    std::string name;
    std::string sex;
    values():name("dummy"),sex("dummy"){} ;

    template<class Archive>   
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(name);
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(sex);
    }
};

class Myclass
{
public:

    Myclass()
    {
        values val1;
        e_group.insert( std::make_pair(1,val1) ) ;
        e_group.insert( std::make_pair(2,val1) ) ;
        p_group.insert( std::make_pair(1,e_group) ) ;
        p_group.insert( std::make_pair(2,e_group) ) ;
    }

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) const
    {
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(e_group);
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(p_group);
    }

    typedef   std::map<int,values> groups;
    typedef   std::map<int,groups> Pgroups;
    groups  e_group;
    Pgroups p_group;
};



int main()
{
    Myclass assetlist;

    auto os = std::ostringstream(std::ios::binary);

    boost::archive::binary_oarchive arch( os, boost::archive::no_header);

    arch << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(assetlist);

    std::string s1 = os.str();

    std::stringstream is( s1, std::ios_base::binary| std::ios_base::out| std::ios_base::in);

    Myclass outObj;

    boost::archive::binary_iarchive iarch (is , boost::archive::no_header );

    iarch >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(outObj);

    return 0; 
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your static assert fails because of the extra 'const' in Myclass::serialize function.
It should look like:

```
template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) 
    { ... }
```

Conserning the BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP() usage see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532331/what-does-boost-serialization-nvp-do-when-serializing-object) question.

Comment: Figured it out , Thanks